# Java program giving me the correct outputs but something is off

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

D286 Java Fundamentals PA

Hi, I'm having a hard time with the School JAVA test. I type in a code that works with different inputs and gives the correct outputs but it is still being marked as wrong on my test. If you see an error on my code I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can point that out. I even tried Chatgpt and it said it was correct. Its hard to know what I'm missing because the test results does not show me what was wrong like in my other classes.

INSTRUCTIONS: Write a program that collects two integer inputs and assigns them to the variables *starting_num* and *multiplier*. Multiply starting_num by multiplier and output the result. Repeat this process two more times, each time multiplying the previous result by the multiplier. The three product outputs should be separated by a white space character, ending with a newline.

MY ANSWER:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        int starting_num;

        int multiplier;

        int results;

        starting_num = scnr.nextInt();

        multiplier = scnr.nextInt();

        results = starting_num * multiplier;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; ++i) {

            System.out.print(results + " ");

            results = results * multiplier;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: One possible way to interpret those instructions is to ask for 3 *different* multipliers.  Does the assignment include any example input/output?

Comment: Are you sure that a recursion is not expected in assignment .

Comment: your code outputs a space after the last number that might be a problem

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stick with the looping approach, then you could output the first result beforehand, and chase that with the space and the next result from within the loop:

```
results = starting_num * multiplier;
System.out.print(results);

for(int i = 1 ; i <= 2; i++) {
  results = results * multiplier;
  System.out.print(" " + results);            
}

System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... If you see an error on my code I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can point that out. ..."*

The only error I see is the additional *white-space* character in your *printed* value.

For example, your value is *"1 2 3 \n"*, whereas it may need to be *"1 2 3\n"*.

And, no need for a  *loop*, it's only 2 steps.

```java
results = starting_num * multiplier;
System.out.print(results);
System.out.print(" " + (results *= multiplier));
System.out.println(" " + (results *= multiplier));
```

Or, in one line, just reduce the variable names.

```java
System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n", r = sn * m, r *= m, r *= m);
```